# DBMS-independent queries

Tags: c#, sql, mysql, sql-server, postgresql

My masters thesis is about discovering bad database design by analyzing metadata and the data stored. We do this by extracting a metadata model from a given DBMS and then running a set of rules on this metadata.

To extend this process with data analysis, we need to allow rules to query the database directly, but we must retain DBMS independence, such that queries can be applied to PostgreSQL, MSSQL and MySQL.

We have discussed a sort of functional construction of queries such as:

```
new Query(new Select(columnID), new From(tableID), new Where(new Equality(columnID1, columnID2)))
```

And then using a DBMS-specific serializer.

Another approach is to let rules handle it all by themselves:

```
public Query QueryDatabase(DBMS dbms)
{
 if (dbms == PostgreSQL) { return "select count(1) from Users"}
 if (dbms == MSSQL) {return ....}
}
```

Are we missing something? Does all this in fact exist in a nice library somewhere? And yes, we have looked at Entity frameworks, but they seem to rely on a statically types model of the database, which for obvious reasons cannot be created.

I should mention that we maintain an extensible rule architecture, allowing end users to implement their own rules.

To clarify what we want to achieve, look at the following query (mssql), it needs two parameters, the name of the table (@table) and the name of the column (@column):

```
DECLARE @TotalCount FLOAT;
SELECT @TotalCount = COUNT(1) FROM [@table];
SELECT SUM(pcount * LOG10(@TotalCount / pcount)) / (LOG10(2) * @TotalCount)  
FROM (SELECT (Count([@column])) as pcount 
      FROM [@table]
      GROUP BY [@column])  as exp1
```

The query measures the amount of information stored in a given attribute, by estimating the entropy. It needs to access all rows in the table. To avoid extracting all rows from the database and transferring them over a slow network connection it is better to express them in SQL an only transfer a single number.

**NOTE**: We **DO** have all the metadata we need. This question is only for accessing data!

I was not very sure of whether to add this to my already long question, edit an existing answer or what todo. Please feel free to advise. ;)

Building on mrnye answer:

```
new Query()
.Variable(varname => FLOAT)
.Set(varname => new Query().Count(1).From(table) )
.Select(new Aggregate().Sum(varname => "pcount * LOG10(varname / pcount)"))
.From(
  new Query()
  .Select(pcount => new Aggregate().Count(column)
  .From(table)
  .GroupBy(column)
)
```

Syntax errors and misuse of lambda statements aside, i played with the idea of using some extension methods for building queries. It does seem as a fairly complex approach. How would you think about such an approach?

Building on the LINQ answer:

```
let totalCount = Table.Count
from uv un from r in Table
           group r by r["attr"]
           select r.Count
select r.Count * Log2((totalCount / r.Count))
```

Seems fairly nice, but a helluva lot to implement...

Comment: I don't know about c#, but the Java JDBC interfaces defines method that the driver has to implement to retrieve metadata (primary keys, foreign keys, nullable etc) for tables. Maybe the equivalent of a JDBC driver in c# offers something similar?

Comment: In an earlier version of this tool we used the JDBC metadata interface. It sure seems nice, but we found several inconsistencies across DBMSs, and ultimately implemented the extractor using INFORMATION_SCHEMA. It was easier that way. ADO.NET actually have a metadata thingy, but it is not as good as JDBC's for our purposes. Please note, this question is not about extracting metadata.

Comment: When relying on INFORMATION_SCHEMA you won't be able to support Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve the same by implementing a custom [LINQ provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) infrastructure. The queries are generic, but the [AST tree visitors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) that generate the SQL queries can be made pluggable. You can even mock a database using a in memory data store and translating your custom LINQ query to a LINQ to objects query!

You would need to create a provider that would know how to extract the column name from the object's indexer. Here is a basic framework that you can extend:

```
// Runs in LinqPad!
public class TableQueryObject
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public object this[string column]
    {
        get { return _data.ContainsKey(column) ? _data[column] : null; }
        set { if (_data.ContainsKey(column)) _data[column] = value; else _data.Add(column, value); }
    }
}

public interface ITableQuery : IEnumerable<TableQueryObject>
{
    string TableName { get; }
    string ConnectionString { get; }
    Expression Expression { get; }
    ITableQueryProvider Provider { get; }
}

public interface ITableQueryProvider
{
    ITableQuery Query { get; }
    IEnumerable<TableQueryObject> Execute(Expression expression);
}

public interface ITableQueryFactory
{
    ITableQuery Query(string tableName);
}


public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    class TableQueryContext : ITableQuery
    {
        private readonly ITableQueryProvider _queryProvider;
        private readonly Expression _expression;

        public TableQueryContext(ITableQueryProvider queryProvider, Expression expression)
        {
            _queryProvider = queryProvider;
            _expression = expression;
        }

        public string TableName { get { return _queryProvider.Query.TableName; } }
        public string ConnectionString { get { return _queryProvider.Query.ConnectionString; } }
        public Expression Expression { get { return _expression; } }
        public ITableQueryProvider Provider { get { return _queryProvider; } }
        public IEnumerator<TableQueryObject> GetEnumerator() { return Provider.Execute(Expression).GetEnumerator(); }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
    }

    public static MethodInfo MakeGeneric(MethodBase method, params Type[] parameters)
    {
        return ((MethodInfo)method).MakeGenericMethod(parameters);
    }

    public static Expression StaticCall(MethodInfo method, params Expression[] expressions)
    {
        return Expression.Call(null, method, expressions);
    }

    public static ITableQuery CreateQuery(this ITableQueryProvider source, Expression expression)
    {
        return new TableQueryContext(source, expression);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TableQueryObject> Select<TSource>(this ITableQuery source, Expression<Func<TSource, TableQueryObject>> selector)
    {
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery(StaticCall(MakeGeneric(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), typeof(TSource)), source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector)));
    }

    public static ITableQuery Where(this ITableQuery source, Expression<Func<TableQueryObject, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery(StaticCall((MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), source.Expression, Expression.Quote(predicate)));
    }
}

class SqlTableQueryFactory : ITableQueryFactory
{

    class SqlTableQuery : ITableQuery
    {
        private readonly string _tableName;
        private readonly string _connectionString;
        private readonly ITableQueryProvider _provider;
        private readonly Expression _expression;

        public SqlTableQuery(string tableName, string connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
            _tableName = tableName;
            _provider = new SqlTableQueryProvider(this);
            _expression = Expression.Constant(this);
        }

        public IEnumerator<TableQueryObject> GetEnumerator() { return Provider.Execute(Expression).GetEnumerator(); }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
        public string TableName { get { return _tableName; } }
        public string ConnectionString { get { return _connectionString; } }
        public Expression Expression { get { return _expression; } }
        public ITableQueryProvider Provider { get { return _provider; } }
    }

    class SqlTableQueryProvider : ITableQueryProvider
    {
        private readonly ITableQuery _query;
        public ITableQuery Query { get { return _query; } }
        public SqlTableQueryProvider(ITableQuery query) { _query = query; }

        public IEnumerable<TableQueryObject> Execute(Expression expression)
        {
            //var connecitonString = _query.ConnectionString;
            //var tableName = _query.TableName;
            // TODO visit expression AST (generate any sql dialect you want) and execute resulting sql
                    // NOTE of course the query can be easily parameterized!
            // NOTE here the fun begins, just return some dummy data for now :)
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                var obj = new TableQueryObject();
                obj["a"] = i;
                obj["b"] = "blah " + i;
                yield return obj;
            }
        }
    }

    private readonly string _connectionString;
    public SqlTableQueryFactory(string connectionString) { _connectionString = connectionString; }
    public ITableQuery Query(string tableName)
    {
        return new SqlTableQuery(tableName, _connectionString);
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    ITableQueryFactory database = new SqlTableQueryFactory("SomeConnectionString");
    var result = from row in database.Query("myTbl")
                 where row["someColumn"] == "1" && row["otherColumn"] == "2"
                 where row["thirdColumn"] == "2" && row["otherColumn"] == "4"
                 select row["a"]; // NOTE select executes as linq to objects! FTW
    foreach(var a in result) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. I actually looked at using LINQ, but missed the pluggable AST tree visitors. Could you provide a few good links? (I am googling the issue as we speak, but you may know a good resource.)

Comment: I added the resources that helped me implement a very similar solution to what you are trying to do. Ultimately you would use the ExpressionVisitor class to build some kind of a Query object (that can be specific per the provided serializer if needed), which is practical since your query needs to have a where clause, which is also a tree structure.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was actually halfway through the LINQ provider tutorial. Looking forward to the AST tree visitors! :)

Comment: Well, I wish you a lot of fun with the Expression API ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the LINQ route is the way to go, but for fun I tried to think of a solution.  It needs some work, but the general idea is to have the query interface fluent and hide the implementation logic behind interfaces.  Just throwing it out there as food for thought...

```
public interface IDBImplementation
{
  public void ProcessQuery(Select query);
}

public class SqlServerImplementation : IDBImplementation
{
  public void ProcessQuery(Select query)
  {
    string sqlQuery = "SELECT " + String.Join(", ", query.Columns)
      + " FROM " + query.TableName + " WHERE " + String.Join(" AND ", query.Conditions);
    // execute query...
  }
}

public class Select
{
  public Select(params string[] columns)
  {
    Columns = columns;
  }

  public string[] Columns { get; set; }
  public string TableName { get; set; }
  public string[] Conditions { get; set; }
}

public static class Extensions
{
  public static Select From(this Select select, string tableName)
  {
    select.TableName = tableName;
    return select;
  }

  public static Select Where(this Select select, params string[] conditions)
  {
    select.Conditions = conditions;
    return select;
  }
}

public static class Main
{
  public static void Example()
  {
    IDBImplementation database = new SqlServerImplementation();

    var query = new Select("a", "b", "c").From("test").Where("c>5", "b<10");

    database.ProcessQuery(query);
  }
}
```

Comment: I like the readability of queries using your approach. How would you go about extending it with SQL variables?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by "SQL variables"?  But anyway to strengthen/build on it what I'd probably do is make the arguments more detailed instead of just strings.  `.Where(new Condition("c", LessThan, 5)` type of thing instead of just `"C<5"`.  But explain what you mean and I can maybe answer more clearly

Answer (score 0):

The most DBMS-independent way to retrieve information about a database is iNFORMATION_SCHEMA.  See [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html), [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx), [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/information-schema.html).

I'm kind of curious what type of rules you're thinking of. :)

Comment: Yes, we know that. We have the metadata extracted already. What we need is a way to query the data stored in the database without having database dependent queries.

Comment: For the record, examples on metadata rules are: tables without primary keys, inconsistent naming convention, inconsistent varchar length (i.e. 92 varchar(32) columns, and one varchar(30) column). Data rules that we are about to implement know are: Columns which only contains values from a small domain (without fk relationships), minor dirty data rules, percentage of row instantiating fk relationships, etc.

Comment: @Benjamin: `select` would work on all three platforms you name, so you could use that.  It doesn't sound like functional query construction would add value to your analysis

Comment: I have tried to elaborate the problem a bit in the question. Hope that it helps. BTW know == now in prev. comment.

Answer (score 0):

What about NHibernate?  http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateforNET

Comment: I don't think NHibernative is applicable in this case, as it is impossible to create classes that can be mapped to the database.